# Add items to query result - Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I'm slowly moving my API to Laravel and coming to grips with the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries).

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE post_type = 3 AND post_status = 1  ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($cms_connection, $query);
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row['post_seo'] = seoUrl($row['post_title']);
        $data['data'][] = $row;
    }
    $data['success'] = true;
    $response = json_encode($data);
}
```

My problem isn't necessarily with getting the query, but as you can see I'm using the result of the query and then injecting it back into the final `array`.

So essentially, I'm fetching rows, transforming some of the attributes fetched, and then injecting the newly created attributes into the resulting array.

This is what I have so far:

```
$posts = DB::table('blog_posts')
    -where(['post_type' => 1, 'post_status' => 1)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it this way

// get your data (yours part of code)

```
$posts = DB::table('blog_posts')
-where(['post_type' => 1, 'post_status' => 1])
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->take(5)->get();
```

// add `post_seo`

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   $post->post_seo = seoUrl($post->post_title);
}
```

// set result array

```
$data['data'] = $posts;
$data['success'] = true;
```

// response

```
$response = response()->json($data);
```

// or in case you want to return it just

```
return response()->json($data);
```

**EDIT**

You could do it also a bit better, using [`Eloquent`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent). If you have such model (you need to add valid namespaces and `use` statements)

```
class BlogModel extends Model 
{
   protected $table = 'blog_posts';
   protected $appends = ['post_seo'];

   public function getPostSeoAttribute($value)
   {
       return seoUrl($this->post_title);
   } 
}
```

(added accessor to `post_seo` attribute and added `post_seo` to results when converting to array)

You can now do (shorter syntax than in previous example):

// get your data

```
$posts = BlogPost::where('post_type',1)
->where('post_status',1)
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->take(5)->get();
```

// response

```
$response = response()->json(['data' => $posts, 'success' => true]);
```

Comment: Oh wow, I've worked with Laravel for a few years and I'd completely missed that `$appends` exists. Thanks! That's going to be very useful.

Comment: @JoelHinz Glad I could learn you something :) I'm also learning all the time and discover new Laravel features :)

Comment: Plus one for the EDIT section!